# How to search for a dependency in nexus repository manager via API?

Tags: spring, maven, nexus

I have all the repository being listed in the nexus. I want an API which I can can use to search for a specific dependency in that nexus. For ex- If i want 'ojdbc' dependency then I should just provide the 'ojdbc' and the api should search within nexus and returns me the list of dependency which contains info like groupId, artifactId and version (and multiple if there are multiple matches).

Also, can i modify the same query to filter using user provided groupId, artifactId and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know about the REST api offered by Nexus which can be used to search an asset and even fetch that asset. 
Please go through - https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api

Searching an asset or component - https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api